# Return filtered JSON variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this function to return `iconurl` value, according to `compname` value:

```
function icons(x){
  var comand = x.toLowerCase();
  var icon= { "ico":[
    {
      "iconname": "X",
      "iconurl": "resources/img/x.jpg"
    }, {
      "iconname": "Y",
      "iconurl": "resources/img/y.png"
    }, {
      "iconname": "Z",
      "iconurl": "resources/img/z.jpg"
    }
  ]};

  var returnedData = $.grep(icon.ico, function (element, index) {
    return element.iconname.toLowerCase() == comand;
  });

  return returnedData[0].iconurl;  
}
```

This works when I call this function only.

When I try to call this function for my variable, I get `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'iconurl' of undefined"`.

```
var compname = "cp/X/";
var regExp = /[^/cp]+/;
var regcomp = regExp.exec(compname);
var icourl = icons(regcomp.toString());
```

```js
function icons(x) {
  var comand = x.toLowerCase();
  var icon = {
    "ico": [{
      "iconname": "X",
      "iconurl": "resources/img/x.jpg"
    }, {
      "iconname": "Y",
      "iconurl": "resources/img/y.png"
    }, {
      "iconname": "Z",
      "iconurl": "resources/img/z.jpg"
    }]
  };

  var returnedData = $.grep(icon.ico, function(element, index) {
    return element.iconname.toLowerCase() == comand;
  });

  return returnedData[0].iconurl;
}

var compname = 'cp/X/';
var regExp = /[^/cp]+/;
var regcomp = regExp.exec(compname);
var icourl = icons(regcomp.toString());
console.log(icourl)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Anyone here where is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: That is probably because none of the elements in the array satisfy the condition, in other words, `returnedData[0]` is `undefined`.

Comment: What is `cp/X/` ? If it is a string, it should be inside quotes.

Comment: Try `return )icon.ico.find((el, i) => el.iconname.toLowerCase() === command) || {}).iconurl`

Comment: @Titus, when I use alert for this function I have the results displayed. The problem is for return. Hassan, sorry, I've edited the post. Rajesh, I don't understand your code. Thanks!

Comment: But your code is working in the code snippet. Is the `icon` data always this or are you fetching this data from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is working fine for the given case.

Second, you are getting following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'iconurl' of undefined

because, your `returnedData` is blank array. This will happen when nothing is matched. So `returnedData[0]` is undefined and not an object.

You should try `(returnedData[0] || {}).iconurl` to avoid this.

Third, since you just want the first value, using `$.grep` is a bit wrong as it will loop till the end to find matches.

You should look into `Array.find`.

```js
function icons(x) {
  var comand = x.toLowerCase();
  var icon = {
    "ico": [{
      "iconname": "X",
      "iconurl": "resources/img/x.jpg"
    }, {
      "iconname": "Y",
      "iconurl": "resources/img/y.png"
    }, {
      "iconname": "Z",
      "iconurl": "resources/img/z.jpg"
    }]
  };
  
  return (icon.ico.find(function(el){
    return el.iconname.toLowerCase() == comand;
  }) || {}).iconurl
}

var compname = 'cp/X/';
var regExp = /[^/cp]+/;
var regcomp = regExp.exec(compname);
var icourl = icons(regcomp.toString());
console.log(icourl)
```

Considering, `Array.find` is not supported by all browsers, you can even try using traditional for.

```js
function icons(x) {
  var comand = x.toLowerCase();
  var icon = {
    "ico": [{
      "iconname": "X",
      "iconurl": "resources/img/x.jpg"
    }, {
      "iconname": "Y",
      "iconurl": "resources/img/y.png"
    }, {
      "iconname": "Z",
      "iconurl": "resources/img/z.jpg"
    }]
  };
  for(var i = 0; i< icon.ico.length; i++) {
    if(icon.ico[i].iconname.toLowerCase() === comand) {
      return icon.ico[i].iconurl;
    }
  }
}

var compname = 'cp/X/';
var regExp = /[^/cp]+/;
var regcomp = regExp.exec(compname);
var icourl = icons(regcomp.toString());
console.log(icourl)
```

Comment: I think it should be `(returnedData[0] || {})` instead of `(returnedData || {})[0]`

Comment: @Titus Thanks. Mistyped. :-)